# Retrieve bibliographic data from DOI code using command line

Tags: bibtex, linux, doi, macos

I am trying  to find a way to retrieve some bibliographic data starting from a DOI code using the Linux/MacOS command line.

For example, suppose I want to get the bibtex entry for the following `DOI: 10.1016/j.algal.2015.04.001`, on this website [on this webite](https://users.aalto.fi/~mkouhia/2016/bibtex-from-dx-doi-org/) I could find the following command which uses the http://dx.doi.org resolver:

```
curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.algal.2015.04.001
```

This command gives the bibtex entry as output. I need to retrieve only some of the citation items, e.g. authors list, or the year, or the title and so on. Do you know any technique to this?

Answer (score 4):

You could retrieve the data in json format and process/filter the data with the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) CLI tool. For example

```
curl -LH "Accept: application/json" http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.algal.2015.04.001 | jq '.title'
```

will show the title as:

```
"Microalgae-utilizing biorefinery concept for pulp and paper industry: Converting secondary streams into value-added products"
```

jq is very powerful, see the [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) or the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).